# How can I add a youtube video on the website and play the video with a modal popup in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a youtube video with a video popup. for example*emphasized text*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width={727} height={409} src="your-video-url" title="YouTube video player" frameBorder={0} allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowFullScreen />;
```

Substitute the `src` with your video url.
Then for the modal part, use [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal).
There are tons of tutorials and solid docs, you should be able to do it pretty easily